# how to use crypt( ) method in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, crypt

I just want to use `crypt()` to generate an encrypted password,and I write a demo which invoke the `crypt()` method.
Here is my code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",crypt("abc","ab"));
    exit(0);
}
```

I compile it using `"gcc tem.c -lcrypt'` and when I run it, everything seems right, but a "segment error" shows up. so please tell me what's wrong with this simple program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you compile with the flag `-Wall` you will see why.

If you read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) you will see that it uses `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before including `<unistd.h>`. It should actually be defined before including *any* header.

If you don't define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` then the `crypt` function will not be prototyped. Then the compiler doesn't know what the actual return type is, or the types and number of arguments. So it will assume that the function returns an `int` and your `printf` expects a string, so there will be a type mismatch that causes the crash.

Comment: The `#define` has to come before _any_ library header - it's a glibc requirement.

Comment: No that's a POSIX requirement.

Comment: @R.. Well, the glibc documentation states it as a requirement, it doesn't reference POSIX compliance in that.

Answer (score 5):

You need this:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

at the top of your source file, before any `#include`.

Alternatively compile with the gcc option `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it could be related to crypto library support.

Try adding:

```
#include <crypt.h>

[mstanislav@pardalislabs ~]$ gcc tem.c -lcrypt
[mstanislav@pardalislabs ~]$ ./a.out  
abFZSxKKdq5s6
```

Looks good for me!

Comment: according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) `crypt.h` should be included for `crypt_r()`, just `unistd.h` should be enought for `crypt()`

Comment: In my testing, I received the segmentation fault that you did with your code. After adding the include as above, it works.

Are you stating the fix didn't fix *your* testing, or just that you believe it shouldn't need my solution?

Comment: A) I'm not the poster, just a casual observer. B) I'm saying, IMO, I don't like adding extra header files when they are not required, and (as stated in the documentation for `crypt()`) as long as you have the functional macro, then that header file is not required.